# Adding file to filegroup with Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, cursor, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql, filegroup

hope you can help me, I'm trying to add a file with the name of the corresponding filegroup, here's my code:

```
DECLARE @SQL1 nvarchar(1024),
    @SQL2 nvarchar(1024), 
    @name varchar(255);

SET @SQL1 = 'DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR GLOBAL
           FOR
           SELECT REPLACE(name,''FG'',''FL'') as name FROM sys.filegroups order by name asc';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL1;
OPEN vend_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

SET  @SQL2 = 'ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
            ADD FILE 
            (
            NAME='+@name+',
            FILENAME = QuoteName(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'+REPLACE(@name,'FL','FG')+'.ndf),
            SIZE = 3MB,
            MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
            FILEGROWTH = 10% 
            )TO FILEGROUP FG_AddressType;'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL2;
PRINT REPLACE(@name,'FG','FL')
FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor INTO @name;  
END   

CLOSE vend_cursor   
DEALLOCATE vend_cursor
```

When I execute the code, I'm getting the following error:
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
    Incorrect syntax near '('

Is it something wrong in my code? Thanks in advance

Comment: The intial `FETCH NEXT` statement is missing the assignment to `@name` variable. Try that and it should fix the issue.

Comment: I did that, didn't work :(

Comment: Try replacing The `FILENAME=` statement with this one `FILENAME = ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'+REPLACE(@name,'FL','FG')+'.ndf'',`